# How to properly format RSpec update test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am learning how to test controllers in Rails. I have this action in my Posts Controller:

```
def update 
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save 
        redirect_to posts_path
        flash[:success] = "Your post has been updated"
    else 
        render 'edit'
    end 
end
```

Pretty basic update action. I want to test it. This is the test I have right now:

require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe PostsController, type: :controller do 

 let!(:test_post) { Post.create(title: "testing", body: "testing") }

 describe "PUT update" do 
    context "when valid" do 
        it "updates post" do 
            patch :update, id: test_post, post: {title: 'other', body: 'other'}
            test_post.reload
            expect(test_post.title).to eq('other')
        end
    end 
 end 
end
```

This test does not pass. This is the error I get from RSpec:

```
1) PostsController PUT update when valid updates post
 Failure/Error: expect(test_post.title).to eq('other')

   expected: "other"
        got: "testing"

   (compared using ==)
```

I would appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: You're doing `post :update` not `patch :update`. Rails uses `put/patch` to update records.

Comment: I actually left that in by accident. Changed it and it still fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update action, you're creating a new `Post`, not updating an existing `Post`:

```
def update 
  @post = Post.new(post_params) <= here
  if @post.save 
    redirect_to posts_path
    flash[:success] = "Your post has been updated"
  else 
    render 'edit'
  end 
end
```

You need to find your existing `Post` record, then update it. Which might look something more like:

```
def update 
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id]) <= might need to be different depending on how you have structured your params
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    redirect_to posts_path
    flash[:success] = "Your post has been updated"
  else 
    render 'edit'
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I need a second pair of eyes.